# Convolution of these distributions implies Stable Distribution

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading about stable distribution. The definition given is the following:

A distribution $F$ is stable if for each $n$ there exist constants $a_{n}$ and $b_{n},$ $a_{n}>0,$ such that, if $X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}$ are independent and have distribution function $F,$ then $a_{n}^{-1}(X_{1}+\cdots +X_{n})+b_{n}$ also have distribution $F.$

I'm stuck proving the next:

Suppose that for all $a,a^{'},b,b^{'}$ there exist $a^{''},b^{''}$ (here $a,a^{'},a^{''}$ are all positive) such that $$F(ax+b)*F(a^{'}x+b^{'})=F(a^{''}x+b^{''}).$$ 
Then, $F$ is stable.

I don't understand the hypotesis of convolution. What does it mean for the proof? I can't see the relation between this and stable distribution.

Any kind o help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theorem 23 in 
http://www.isibang.ac.in/~adean/infsys/database/notes/Infinitely%20Divisible%20and%20Stable%20Distributions.pdf

has a proof.
 BTW, the convolution hypothesis is equivalent to the following: if $\{X,Y\}$ is i.i.d with the given distribution then, for any $a,b >0$ there exist $c>0, d \in \mathbb R$ such that $aX+bY$ has the same distribution as $cX+d$. 
PS : Theorem 21 in above notes has a more powerful result.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy. The notes are very helpful. I've been read for a while and I think can understand the proof of Theorem 23. My doubt is about your comment, or may be I don't understand the notation of the convolution hypothesis: $F(ax+b)*F(a^{'}x+b^{'})=F(a^{''}x+b^{''})$ means that the sum of random variables $(aX+b)+(a^{'}X+b^{'})$ has the same distribution as $(a^{''}X+b^{''})?$ Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: I don't get  the reason you mention is equivalent of the convolution hypothesis.

Comment: I get it @Kavi Rama Murthy! Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @Squird37 you may also be interested in visiting statmathbc.wordpress.com where I have posted several lecture notes on Probability and Analysis. The notes on Infinite divisibility are in three volumes.

Comment: Thanks @Kavi Rama Murthy! I've been reading a little about Analysis. The problems look so great. I'm going to check Probability notes too.